# Magento 2 - How to find out where certain blocks are defined?

Tags: magento2, layout

I try to remove some blocks on the 404 site:

[image]

but I have no idea where they are defined.
I searched in the layout file **vendor\magento\module-catalog-search\view\frontend\layout\catalogsearch_result_index.xml** and searched other **catalogsearch_result_index.xml** files but I am unable to figure out where these are defined so I can remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you are looking is cms page with identifier `no-route`

You can edit content form CMS pages.
If you want to remove right section, just change page layout from `2 column right bar` to `1 column`

Hope above will help!

**Update**

You can update/remove section from

> app/design/frontend/Package/my-theme/Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_noroute.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body/>
        <referenceBlock name="sidebar.main" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I changed it to 1 column, but now the blocks are just showing at the bottom

Comment: Yes, I saw that...let me check...

Comment: check my updates, You can remove sidebar from layout...